# SFMCURLTypeAction constant in sfmc_handleURL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, android, sdk

I am implementing the `sfmc_handleURL` function ([doc reference](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/implementation-urlhandling.html)), and I found there are 3 possible constants for the `type` argument:

- SFMCURLTypeCloudPage
- SFMCURLTypeOpenDirect
- SFMCURLTypeAction

**What does each one represent?** I can't find a good documentation explaining each use.

Answer (score 0):

- `CloudPages` are used for `Inbox Messaging`
- `OpenDirect` are URLs passed in "Normal" Push Notifications
- `Action` are used for App links, etc.

Comment: Gotcha! can you elaborate a bit more on the `Action` one? what do you mean by app links and what else uses this type besides app links? Thanks!

Comment: Most customers use this for app deeplinks: myapp://something